# StencilJS IonContent scroll event firing to child component

Tags: javascript, ionic-framework, ionic4, jsx, stenciljs

IonContent has its own scroll event which I need to listen for in a child component.

I was listening for the window scroll event which was not firing and I realised it was wrapped in the IonContent element which handles its own scroll events.

An example of my layout is below

```
<ion-content scrollEvents={ true } onIonScroll={ this.windowScrolled.bind(this) }>
    <bf-filter-selections scrollElement={this.ionContent} ref={(e) => this.filterElementWrapper = e}></bf-filter-selections>
</ion-content>
```

I've tried a few things:

1. I've tried calling the child component "windowScroll" method from
   the parent when the scroll on IonContent happens
2. I've tried passing a reference of the parent to the child so I can
   listen for the scroll event
3. I've tried creating a property on the child which I update when the
   scroll event happens then watching for the changes

This may come back to some basic js knowledge that I'm lacking but it's frustrating as I can't seem to get the event firing in my child component when the content is scrolling.

Out of the things I've tried, here's why they didn't work

1) Calling the child component's method from the parent, the code is telling me it can't find "windowScroll" on the child.

filterElementWrapper is HTMLElement

```
 filterElementWrapper: any;
 windowScrolled(e: any) {

    this.filterElementWrapper.windowScroll();

  }
```

Child component method

```
  @Listen('onscroll')
  @Watch('scrollOffset')
  public windowScroll() {
    console.log('scroll');

    if (window.pageYOffset > this.resultHeaderElementOffset) {
      this.resultHeaderElement.classList.add("sticky");
    } else {
      this.resultHeaderElement.classList.remove("sticky");
    }
  }
```

2) Tried passing a reference of the parent component to the child

I don't have the code any more that supports this but basically in the child component, I created a property that was of type "any" and passed a reference of the parent to the child.

I then created a "Listen('ionScroll', { target: this.scrollElement})".

The method is never fired in the child.

3) Created a property on the child component called "scrollOffset". I updated this property when the scroll was fired and "Watch" for the property changes in the child component. Again, the method is not firing.

Main wrapper setting the scroll offset property

```
<ion-content scrollEvents={ true } onIonScroll={ this.windowScrolled.bind(this) }> 
   <bf-filter-selections scroll-offset={this.scrollTop} scrollElement={this.ionContent} ref={(e) => this.filterElementWrapper = e}></bf-filter-selections>
</ion-content>
```

The state property set in the parent

```
@State() scrollTop: number = 0;
```

Updating the state property on scroll

```
windowScrolled(e: any) {
    this.scrollTop = e.detail.currentY;
}
```

Child property which has been watched

```
@Prop() scrollOffset: number;
```

The method which is watching the property changes

```
  @Listen('onscroll')
  @Watch('scrollOffset')
  public windowScroll() {
    console.log('scroll');

    if (window.pageYOffset > this.resultHeaderElementOffset) {
      this.resultHeaderElement.classList.add("sticky");
    } else {
      this.resultHeaderElement.classList.remove("sticky");
    }
  }
```

In all instances, the method is not being called.

Comment: Maybe you can share more informations why your solutions didn't work and maybe also provide some more code snippets to really get an idea of what you've done so far.

Comment: @ChristianMeyer - I've added some examples of what I've attempted. Thanks for the feedback

Answer (score 2):

I'm not 100% sure why your method 3 has started working, but I assume it's because the `onIonScroll` handler updates the `scrollOffset` state, which then triggers the `@Watch()` decorated method.

---

You're mixing up a few things here, so I'll try to clear this up a bit first: if an element emits an event `<EventName>`, then you can bind a listener to that element by adding a `on<EventName>` property to it, e. g.:

```html
<my-button onclick={console.log} />
```

binds the function `console.log` to the `click` event. The equivalent of doing the same thing in JavaScript would be:

```js
document.querySelector('my-button').addEventListener('click', console.log);
```

If you did `addEventListener('onclick')`, that would not work because the event name is `click` and not `onclick`. You only add the `on` prefix if you want to add an event handler to an element in HTML (see [DOM onevent handlers](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/Events/Event_handlers)). Alternatively, this would also work in JavaScript:

```js
document.querySelector('my-button').onclick = console.log;
```

(the difference being that you can only set one `onclick` property but you can atttach multiple `click` event listeners if you use `addEventListener`)

Note that the case matters in JavaScript but not in HTML, so

```html
<my-button onClick={console.log} />
```

is equivalent to the first example.

---

> Ideally I wanted to listen to the parent component's scroll event in the child and I still can't get that working.

This is not possible because events can only bubble up the DOM tree but not down. The concept is "events up, props down". For your case the cleanest solution I can think of is similar to what you already tried: listen for the event in the parent and then pass the necessary info down to the child as a prop:

```
import { h, Component, State } from '@stencil/core';
import { ScrollDetail } from '@ionic/core';

@Component({ tag: 'my-parent' })
export class Parent {
  @State() scrollTop = 0;

  setScrollTop = (e: CustomEvent<ScrollDetail>) => {
    this.scrollTop = e.detail.scrollTop;
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <ion-content scrollEvents onIonScroll={this.setScrollTop}>
        <child-component scrollTop={this.scrollTop} />
      </ion-content>
    );
  }
}
```

Instead of using `onIonScroll` as a property on `<ion-content>`, you could also use the `@Listen()` decorator like this:

```
@Listen('ionScroll')
setScrollTop(e: CustomEvent<ScrollDetail>) {
  this.scrollTop = e.detail.scrollTop;
}
```

Here your error was to use `'onscroll'` as the event name.

---

I saw that you also tried passing down a reference to the scroll element to the child. The `ion-content` element is not the one that's actually scrolling, so it provides a method [`getScrollElement`](https://ionicframework.com/docs/api/content#methods) that gives you the correct element if you want to do "native" stuff like accessing the underlying `scroll` event or manually accessing `scrollTop` of that element (which I assume is what you tried to do from your child).

```js
customElements.whenDefined('ion-content').then(() => {
  document.querySelector('ion-content').getScrollElement().then(el => {
    el.addEventListener('scroll', () => console.log(el.scrollTop));
  });
});
```

Comment: Thanks, I had used "scroll" in a previous attempt. I don't know why I used onscroll as I do know the difference but I appreciate you taking the time to explain it. What would you say the cleanest method is? The method I'm using is currently working as expected and ultimately they'll end up doing the same job but from a "best practice" point of view, what would be your opinion?

Comment: From a "best practice" point of view the solution is what I posted here: listen for the event in the parent, then pass the specifically needed data to the child as a prop. This is Stencil best practice, see e. g. https://stenciljs.com/docs/properties: "Children components should not know about or reference parent components, so Props should be used to pass data down from the parent to the child.", or the first info box of https://stenciljs.com/docs/methods.

Comment: I'd never looked at the method decorator before, that would have made item 1 work also. I tried exposing the child method as public but didn't realise I had to decorate it as well. That would have been another potential route to go down. Thanks

Comment: Yup that's also possible but not best practice... so far there's only one occurrence in our app where I found it to be more clear than "events up, props down". Clearer in the sense that the method is used by both the child and the parent, but it belongs in the child's code.

Answer (score 0):

For some reason, method 3 has started working.

I'm not sure if it's because I've done a clean build of the project after I posted the updates but the method is now being called and everything is working as expected.

One thing though, I'd still like to know if this is the best approach? Ideally I wanted to listen to the parent component's scroll event in the child and I still can't get that working.

If anyone has a cleaner solution, please let me know

Answer (score 0):

Personally I would go for the first one because it is nearest to an interrupt / push. So if the state changes the child component gets immediately the information of a state change.

You was really close but you just have to add the [@Method](https://stenciljs.com/docs/methods) decorator to your child function. This decorator makes the function public available and you can call it from the parent. From my point of view that is the easiest and best way to realise that.

Just a side notice for your second and third solution here: Both concepts started working because stencil watches the properties and **rerenders** the component when a change has been applied. In some cases this isn't needed - that creates unwanted overhead. Also i think the watch is actually designed as a polling but im not sure about this.

Further you can't get the parent event since the behaviour of an event is like - it starts from the root and 'goes down' through the tree until it reaches the interacted element. This is called [capturing phase](https://javascript.info/bubbling-and-capturing). Once it reached the element it bubbles up. So theoretically events go down and **you can capture them** but only if the element is higher in the hierarchy then the interaction was.

Comment: Thanks Christian. I noticed the odd behaviour again today. I removed all the code that was no longer needed and added the listener event rather than implicitly calling the onscroll and it all stopped working. I had to terminate the process and run the build again to make it start working. Quite frustrating as I ended up spending about 2 hours trying to figure it out when my first approach would have probably worked but the build wasn’t updating for some reason